# Schengen Visa : What does the information mean?

Tags: visas, schengen, terminology

Recently I have got a Schengen visa with this information :

- Visa validity : 7-7-13 to 7-12-13
- Duration of stay : 90 days
- Number of entries : multiple
- Visa category : C .

Can anyone please explain the above information?
For example, I would like to know what they mean by multiple entries? How many times I can enter the Schengen area within 90 days?

Answer (score 5):

This is simple:

You have a visa valid from July 7, 2013 to December 7, 2013.  In that time you can enter Schengen from a non-Schengen country and leave the Schengen area for non-Schengen country multiple times with total duration of your presence in the Schengen Area should not exceed 90 days.

Comment: Maybe you can add that multiple entries means exiting the Schengen are and reenter it. It sounds obvious but there are a lot of questions about whether entering a Schengen country from another Schengen country counts as an entry.

Comment: @Vince Ok.  Added.

Answer (score 3):

A Schengen visa can allow one, two or multiple entries. Beyond two-entry visas, there are no other restrictions on the number of entries. Multiple therefore means “as often as you like”, provided you respect the other conditions (period of validity, duration of stay, purpose of the trip, financial means, etc.).